# JasperReports: How to add a WHERE statement in SQL query depending on a Boolean parameter?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports, where-clause

How can I add a sub where statement in SQL if my Boolean parameter is true in *JasperReports*?
For example, I have my SQL as below:

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE region = "Canada" ORDER BY name
```

If my parameter is true, I would like to add *`and isactive = 'Y'`* just before *`ORDER BY`*.
Anybody knows how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional parameter for setting additional clause value. After that you can use [*`$P!{}`*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query) syntax in query.

The sample:

```xml
<parameter name="param" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
<parameter name="whereCond" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{param} ? " AND isactive='Y'" : ""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM shops WHERE region='Canada' $P!{whereCond} ORDER BY name]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. The issue is due to ! for parameters which are compiled before the query is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from shops where region = "Canada"
AND isActive = CASE WHEN @var = 'True' then 'Y' ELSE isActive END
order by name
```

Comment: Hi rs, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried but doesn't work. As I understand your code, it will be `AND isActive = isActive` if my parameter (eg. $P{param1}) is false ?

Comment: @user1745968 Yes if parameter is false it will be `AND isActive = isActive`, what error do you get?

Comment: The error is Error "executing SQL statement". As I want is nothing changed if the param is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that direct in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE region = "Canada"
AND (@param <> `True` OR isActive = 'Y')
-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--<< Condition: Your param is not true------
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Hi @hims056,
I tried 
`AND ($P{param} <> 'True' OR isActive = 'Y')`
I tried @ as well, all returned error "Error executing SQL statement"

Comment: it will exceed the max characters allowed. I just paste where clause and I changed the param (ExcludeClosedShops) to String with Y or N.

`where pos.ad_client_id = $P{CLIENT}
 and pos.ad_org_id in ($P!{ORG})
 and pos.m_brand_id in ($P!{BRAND})
 and pos.c_activity_id in ($P!{ACTIVITY})
 and pos.c_salesregion_id in ($P!{REGION})
        AND ($P{ExcludeClosedShops}.equals("N") OR pos.isActive = 'Y')
 and cash.isposorder = 'Y'
 AND STATEMENTDATE BETWEEN $P{STARTDATE} and $P{ENDDATE}`

By the way, the sql works well without the additional "AND"

Comment: and the param definition as below:

<parameter name="ExcludeClosedShops" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>

Comment: What I tried myself is  `$P{ExcludeClosedShops}.equals("Y") ? "and pos.isactive='Y'" : " "` but also doesn't work.